# pip install -c dglteam dgl failed

Tags: python, conda, dgl

I saw from another thread that current channels could affect it. I would like to install dgl 0.4.3. and pip commands or install from environment files have failed. How can I get it installed? Below is the error log. Many thanks.

Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

- dgl

Current channels:

- https://conda.anaconda.org/dglteam/osx-arm64
- https://conda.anaconda.org/dglteam/noarch
- https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/osx-arm64
- https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

```
https://anaconda.org
```

and use the search bar at the top of the page.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the platforms [the **dglteam** Conda channel](https://anaconda.org/dglteam/dgl) builds for:

[image: supported platforms]

Currently, this does not show **osx-arm64**, which is what the errors indicate OP is on. Instead, either emulate the **osx-64** platform with Rosetta 2 or run in a container (e.g., https://hub.docker.com/u/dgllib).

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply! As I am new to this, do you have any links to instructions on how I can do this? I visited the links you provided but I only see things like GPU image and CPU image for which I am not sure what they are used for. Thanks

Comment: Containers are portable compute contexts. Those linked are for the Docker framework and provide preconfigured installations of `dgl`. Rosetta 2 might be less of a learning curve, since that is provided by MacOS and lets one run Terminal while emulating the typical Intel architecture (x86_64).